# Nginx - Downloads file if I only allow myself to see it

Tags: php, nginx

```
    location = /index.php {
    allow MY-IP-HERE;
    deny all;
    }
```

With this configuration, because I do not wish for others to see what I'm working on in maintenance, whenever I go to index.php it downloads the file instead of letting me see it.

However if I disable it I can view it just fine.

Am I missing something here?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in
            # php.ini
            # With php5-cgi alone: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Is this a local or hosted instance of nginx?

Comment: Hosted on a virtual server running Nginx

Comment: what gets downloaded when this happens? 0-byte file? or your "access denied" page? could be whatever you've set as your "denied" page is outputting an inapropriate mime type.

Comment: It downloads the php file with everything inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you probably later in your .conf file is you pass .php requests to a PHP CGI handler. Here is an example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

When you add a location before that, it skips the one that hands it off to FastCGI, so it's treating your PHP file like static content.

If you want your IP address restriction to apply to all php files, then move your allow/deny inside of that location match (and get rid of the other one since its empty now), like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        allow MY-IP-HERE;
        deny all;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in
        # php.ini
        # With php5-cgi alone: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

If you want it for *only* `index.php`, then you can nest the location matches:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    location ~ index\.php$ {
            allow MY-IP-HERE;
            deny all;
        }
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in
        # php.ini
        # With php5-cgi alone: fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I believe that will allow continuing to pass to CGI. If not, then you may just need to duplicate the FastCGI section for index.php.

Comment: I've added the only thing I see in my file with fastcgi in it, as you probably can tell - I'm not a big genius with Nginx yet.

Comment: @Codey93 OK, so you have a choice. Do you want *all* PHP files to be restricted to your IP address, or just index.php? If you want all to be restricted, then get rid of your first `location` and move the allow / deny lines to the top of the second block you posted.

Comment: Yes! That works, thank you so much - saved me a a lot of hours of dumb mistakes.